# cross-fade transition in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a big issue with Firefox fading and sliding effect.Please look at the link and try to click on left and right buttons. You 'll notice that slides not functioning correct:
http://jsfiddle.net/marb315/7JFLf/
This happening only in Firefox...
Can anyone please  help me out?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well if you keep

```
initialized : true,
```

in the config it works at-least in firefox, better than not working at all....but yeah still there are some issues...

in the

```
$('#slider-two').movingBoxes
```